# C# Code size and Code execution time

Tags: c#, performance

Is there any way to find what is a size of a code and what is its execution time so I can compare two codes and decide which is better?

For example lets say I want to find the size and execution time of this

Code 1

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
   sum+=1;
}
```

and this

Code 2

```
for(int i=0; i<=4; i++)
{
   sum = sum + 1;
}
```

to decide which is better (I don't care about this example now). For example the result will be:

```
Code 1:
Size: ? KB
Time: ? ms

Code 2:
Size: ? KB
Time: ? ms
```

Comment: Why not just use `sum++`? It uses `inc` instead of `add`. And `inc` is generally faster...

Comment: *(After translation of the MSIL)

Comment: @ColeJohnson My guess is that it's the kind of optimization that a compiler/JITter is doing for you

Comment: @ColeJohnson I don't care about this example but you right :)

Comment: @Cole: I hope that we are beyond those kinds of "optimizations" with today's compiler technology. A more convincing argument would be that the alternative is more idiomatic/easier to read/faster to write.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could either use ANTS Profiler http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/ (payable product but they have a Trial version) or some other Profiler product (ANTS, vTune, OptimizeIt, DevPartner, YourKit, dotTrace) on the market.

You may also intstrument the functions by yourself by setting up some unit tests that execute those 2 functions using a manual StopWatch instrumentation to compare execution time (quicker and less expensive). Unit tests would also allow for assuring that you do not have any regressions on performance if you need to change the implementation later. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

```
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    var result = CallFunction();
    stopWatch.Stop();
    var executionTime = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Comment: May I suggest the use of [`Stopwatch.StartNew()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

To measure execution time you should use [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) - you will need to run multiple iterations multiple times and average them out if you want a proper benchmark.

```
var sw = new StopWatch();
sw.Start();

// do a million iterations

sw.Stop();

var time = sw.Elapsed;
```

As for in memory sizes - you can use one of the many memory profilers available - [ANTS memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) are two commercial options.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class (See the `Length` property) to determine the size of a file.

You can use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class to determine how long it takes to run the program.

Comment: Thank you for Stopwatch but FileInfo was not what I needed